# How can I resolve TypeScript warning for Antd Table's onChange handler in the official Antd AJAX example

Tags: typescript, antd

I am trying to resolve the following warning:

```
<Table
      columns={columns}
      rowKey={(record) => record.login.uuid}
      dataSource={data}
      pagination={tableParams.pagination}
      loading={loading}
      onChange={handleTableChange}
    />
```

`onChange` function gives following warning shown by Visual Studio Code:

```
Type '(pagination: TablePaginationConfig, filters: Record<string, FilterValue>, sorter: SorterResult<DataType>) => void' is not assignable to type '(pagination: TablePaginationConfig, filters: Record<string, FilterValue | null>, sorter: SorterResult<DataType> | SorterResult<...>[], extra: TableCurrentDataSource<...>) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'filters' and 'filters' are incompatible.
    Type 'Record<string, FilterValue | null>' is not assignable to type 'Record<string, FilterValue>'.
      'string' index signatures are incompatible.
        Type 'FilterValue | null' is not assignable to type 'FilterValue'.
          Type 'null' is not assignable to type '(boolean | Key)[]'.ts(2322)
InternalTable.d.ts(21, 5): The expected type comes from property 'onChange' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & TableProps<DataType> & { children?: ReactNode; } & { ref?: Ref<HTMLDivElement> | undefined; }'
(property) TableProps<DataType>.onChange?: ((pagination: TablePaginationConfig, filters: Record<string, FilterValue | null>, sorter: SorterResult<DataType> | SorterResult<...>[], extra: TableCurrentDataSource<...>) => void) | undefined
```

It's taken from official Antd docs hosted here: https://ant.design/components/table#components-table-demo-ajax

If you want to quickly try out the code in VS Code I have added it to a Vite based React App in this Github Repo: https://github.com/pritambarhate/antdtablewarning

TSC version is: 4.9.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Table Filter can be any value (number, string, boolean null...) but in `handleTableChange` filter type, it doesn't include null type. You can add null in `filters: Record<string, FilterValue | null>` but you also need to add null in `TableParams` interface filters and you'll have one more typescript error for sorter after fixing filters type. To fix both issues, you can simply use TableProps onChange type.

```
import type { TableProps } from "antd/es/table";

const App = () => {
 const handleTableChange: TableProps<DataType>["onChange"] = (pagination, filters, sorter) => {
    ...rest of the code
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. For future readers, I have added the solution branch on github with required code changes: https://github.com/pritambarhate/antdtablewarning/tree/solution